# Horizontal Recyclerview inside a Vertical Scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a situation where I have a Recyclerview which slides horizontally inside a ScrollView. Now the situation is when I do a horizontal swipe on the Recyclerview, instead of scrolling the cardviews inside Recyclerview, it scrolls the screen up, which disturbs the user experience.

Any solution or approach to avoid vertical scrolling when the person is doing a horizontal swipe on Recyclerview?

Comment: This is a typical `scrollable in scrollable` **scroll-conflict**. And the reason why you should **never** design a layout this way.

Comment: I know that Google Design Guidelines discourages it, but there are some legitimate use case where multiple items needs to be shown in a line when it numbers more than 5 instead of breaking it into 3 lines. The idea by reducing the 3 lines to a single line is so that everything in the screen is highlighted and visible at the one go, without the user need to scroll to the bottom. Sometimes due to limited real estate space, after second line, when the final section below it is not visible completely, user might assume that there would be offers, and would leave the screen.

Comment: [SOLVED]  Solved here for vertical recycler view in horizontal scroll view, can be done similarly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37619660/1303639

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually quite simple.
put the horizontal RecycleView as an item in a RecycleView, instead of using a scrollview. 
then when you scroll it behaves as you want it to.
Thats what I did and it works perfectly